# Report standard deviation in Rendering results

Tags: raytracing, rendering, pathtracing, monte-carlo

I noticed that a common metrics for image quality assessment (Monte Carlo path tracing) is MSE between the generated image and a reference one. My question is: why isn't the standard deviation ever mentioned? Isn't it necessary? Shouldn't we generate n number of samples, compare them all with the reference, and then report the average and the standard deviation?
This is how I have always seen results in technical papers, except for papers in Graphics. I am wondering if the fact that path tracing is unbiased plays a role in the missing std dev. 
Thank you.

Comment: It's very hard to get unbiased estimation of the standard deviation, not so for variance, where Bessel's correction provides an unbiased estimate.